# Openshift changes Java version to 6

Tags: java, version, openshift

I am trying to deploy my application to openshift, but everytime I try to push it there it switches the java version to 6 even though I have a java7 marker.
Cartridges I use: 
 
**AS**: WildFly Application Server 8.0.0.Final 
**DB**: MongoDB 2.4

The exception on the openshift server is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jboss/as/jmx/PluggableMBeanServerBuilder : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

(I do not have PluggableMBeanServerBuilder in my pom.xml as dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have java7 marker file under .openshift/markers directory? Every OpenShift application has a .openshift directory that contains few configuration files. The java7 marker tells OpenShift to use java 7. If this file is not present then OpenShift will fallback to Java 6.

Comment: I have it, however I have it only in the maven submodule, which I would like to deploy only and that's probably the problem. However, I got it to work deploying only the war and not the project itself.